# How to use count method with my_model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to work with [Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) and I'm running into an issue with figuring out how I can use the count method with an array.

I want to count the total number of personal unread messages the logged user has received.

So I was going to try the following call:

```
$unread_messages = $this->personal_messsages->count_by();
```

However, I need to also pass in the `user_id` of the user and an integer to know if the message was unread or read.

Any ideas on how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, count_by() only works off a single field & value, not an array (unless he's updated). You'll have to write your own for this

Have a look at this link to see examples of all the MY_Model functions: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/01/using-jamie-rumbelows-my_model

EDIT: I may stand corrected on this one: try passing in array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'status'=>1); (adjusted for your own values), that may work